# unable to use readline() function in c++ windows form application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, serial-port

I am trying to make a windows form application for reading message through serial port. For this I use a function 'Ports()' for detecting serial Port, and to display the detected serial Port I use a comboBox. The body of Ports() function is here:-

```
void Ports(void)
{
 array<String^>^ serialPorts = nullptr;

 // Get a list of serial port names.
 serialPorts = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
//list detcted ports on combobox
 this->comboBox_Ports->Items->AddRange( serialPorts );

}
```

similarly I use another function and a ComboBox for setting Baudrate, here is the code for baudrate function:-

```
void BaudRate(void)
{
this->comboBox_BaudRate->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(3) {L"9600",L"38400", L"115200"});
}
```

Now I use a Button for setting COM port, Baudrate and initialize the serial port, here is the code for initializing button:-

```
private: System::Void button_init_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


                this->_serialPort->PortName=this->comboBox_Ports->Text;
                     this->textBox1->Text=this->comboBox_Ports->Text;
                this->_serialPort->BaudRate=Int32::Parse(this->comboBox_BaudRate->Text);
                     this->textBox2->Text=this->comboBox_BaudRate->Text;
            this->_serialPort->ReadTimeout = 1500;
            this->_serialPort->WriteTimeout = 1500;
                this->_serialPort->Open();

             }
```

Now finally , I use a button to read the value from serial port, here is the code for read button:-

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String^ name;

                      name=this->_serialPort->ReadLine();

              this->textBox_Read->Text=name;


         }
```

Now when I use this application , my COM port and BaudRate is setting fine but I am getting this error in ReadLine() function:-

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in System.dll
```

So, please tell me why I am not getting my values.